# Mind-bending code understanding when checking if a point is in polygon in python

Tags: python, linear-algebra

I'm studying how to check a point in a polygon. The thinking is about counting the times a horizontal line intersects with the polygon edges.

My previous study is to find a code from the internet, which is:

```py
def IsPtInPoly(aLon, aLat, pointList):  
    ''''' 
    :param aLon: double Longitude 
    :param aLat: double Latitude
    :param pointList: list [(lon, lat)...] The vertex of the polygon should be either clockwise or counter clockwise
    '''  

    iSum = 0  
    iCount = len(pointList)  

    if(iCount < 3):  
        return False  


    for i in range(iCount):  

        pLon1 = pointList[i][0]  # ith point
        pLat1 = pointList[i][1]  # ith point

        if(i == iCount - 1):  

            pLon2 = pointList[0][0] # start from beginning 
            pLat2 = pointList[0][1] # start from beginning 
        else:  
            pLon2 = pointList[i + 1][0]  #(i+1)th point
            pLat2 = pointList[i + 1][1]  #(i+1)th point

        if ((aLat >= pLat1) and (aLat < pLat2)) or ((aLat>=pLat2) and (aLat < pLat1)):  

            if (abs(pLat1 - pLat2) > 0):  

                pLon = pLon1 - ((pLon1 - pLon2) * (pLat1 - aLat)) / (pLat1 - pLat2)
                # That's what confuse me.

                if(pLon < aLon):  
                    iSum += 1  

    if(iSum % 2 != 0):  
        return True  
    else:  
        return False
```

My question is: What is `pLon = pLon1 - ((pLon1 - pLon2) * (pLat1 - aLat)) / (pLat1 - pLat2)` talking about and why it can get the x coordinate with the polygon edges. I want detailed explanation. Thx

Comment: Isn't this just line equation? Sort of x(y) = x_0 - (dy/dx)*(y_1, y_a)?

Comment: Yes. when transforming the equation to: (pLon1-pLon2)/(pLat1-pLat2) = (pLon1-pLon)/(pLat1-aLat), it becomes less obscure and more staightforward to understand now.